# How to update Contract Record when related Quote record is changed

Tags: trigger, update, record

I'm aiming to update a Contract Date field when the Date field on a corresponding Quote record is changed. The Quote record is linked to the Contract via lookup.

I already have a formula on the Contract object that reads the Quote date. Does this formula get re-evaluated when the Quote is modified? If so, then I can use this as a condition in the trigger.

I want this trigger to run only if a specific Date field on the Quote object is changed. There isn't an ischanged function in Apex I can leverage. How do I design this trigger?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is no function like isChanged() in apex trigger. There is an idea which posted in forum for the functionality.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=087300000007LI2AAM

However you can check if the value is changed through apex trigger using **Trigger.oldMap**. You can get lot of example over google. One of the example is here how to use the functionality.

```
// Check a checkbox only when an Opp is changed to Closed Won!
trigger Winning on Opportunity (before update) {
  for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
    // Access the "old" record by its ID in Trigger.oldMap
    Opportunity oldOpp = Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id);

    // Trigger.new records are conveniently the "new" versions!
    Boolean oldOppIsWon = oldOpp.StageName.equals('Closed Won');
    Boolean newOppIsWon = opp.StageName.equals('Closed Won');

    // Check that the field was changed to the correct value
    if (!oldOppIsWon && newOppIsWon) {
      opp.I_am_Awesome__c = true;
    }
  }
}
```